# Using Networked-Aframe with aframe-react

Tags: reactjs, webpack, aframe, easyrtc, aframe-react

I'm trying to make a multiplayer game using the Networked-Aframe library with aframe-react. The big roadblock I've run into is I can't simultaneously run:

```
react-scripts start
```

to run react and

```
node ./src/vendor/easyrtc-server.js
```

to run my server.

Maybe create a production build of my react app, then run the server?

*How do I get these two working together?*

My easyrtc-server.js: https://pastebin.com/PJ0UchSi

Answer (score 1):

You can add new scripts to your `package.json` file to run different commands.

**Example**

```
{
  "name": "someapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
     // some dependecies
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "custombuild": "npm build && node ./src/vendor/easyrtc-server.js"
  }
}
```

Then when you can run,

```
npm custombuild
```

This command will first build your app and then start your server.

Comment: Tweaked my question a bit, I'm not just looking to make them run simultaneously, I need the server to work with my fully built react app.

It works already if you write straight to the index.html file, but not when actually using react.